# C# Why is there no implementation for GetAwaiter (StorageFile) when using method CreateFileAsync?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I tried to make use of SQLite in C# like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases).
In the step "Initialize the SQLite database" I get the problem for the line

```
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sqliteSample.db", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

because:

```
Error CS4036 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?
```

I am `using System;` already. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What is .net framework version?

Comment: In the App.config it says `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />`

Comment: What happens if you do `await CreateFileAsync(whatever).AsTask();` ? That's an extension in `System.Threading.Tasks`

Comment: it tells me that there is no implementation and it could miss a using directive or assembly reference

Comment: And are you missing the using directive or assembly reference?

Comment: I dont know to be honest - it doesn't tell which directive or assembly reference could be missing.

Comment: As I said **it is an extension method in `System.Threading.Tasks`.**

Comment: Where is the file located (sqliteSample.db)?  The code expects it to be in the Current LocalFolder.

Comment: Eric: I declared `using System.Threading.Tasks;` at the top. It is marked as unused and the AsTask is marked with the error I mentioned.
jdweng: The file doesn't exist yet. I can't even compile the programm because of the error.

Comment: @NullOrNotNull You probably miss System.Threading.Tasks. Please check here https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks/ how you can install it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<UserNotification>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515716/iasyncoperationireadonlylistusernotification-does-not-contain-a-definition)